# Summing based on Condition inside VBA and pasting Value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to come up with some code to sum all values from a different sheet inside vba and paste them as values. I would like to run each row at a time (a row all has the same condition and just gets data from different place based on the column number)

How can i do run the sum based on condition this way?

```
Dim i as Integer 'Rows
Dim n as Integer 'Column

For i = 9 To 24
    For n = 3 To 21

    Next
Next
```

Comment: A loop like that would be extremely slow. a) why don't you use formulas for that? Formulas are Excel's strength and pretty fast compared to VBA. b) you can even write the formulas with VBA if you need some kind of automation c) If you really have to use VBA use the [WorksheetFunction.Sum method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.sum). • Please share some background information why you have to do this and why you have to use VBA, so we can provide a suitable answer.

Comment: If conditions come into the game there is also `=SUMIF()` and `=SUMIFS()` formulas. Or as VBA equivalent [WorksheetFunction.SumIf method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.sumif) and [WorksheetFunction.SumIfs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.sumifs).

Comment: The formulas are making the excel extremely slow because it is complemented with conditional formatting, the file is basically dragging itself. I was trying to come up with some solution to just use a dictionary or a loop to run and then just be able to analyze the file afterwards with mostly values

Comment: Give WorksheetFunctions a try. A loop will be even slower I guess. Check it out.

Comment: You could look at [memory-based arrays](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-array/) to grab the data from each sheet, then run the sum from the arrays. Accessing the cells on the worksheets directly can be very slow (if there are lots of cells to access). We could give more advice if you post examples of the data on the different sheets and more details about your code.

Comment: Thank you @PeterT , i'm looking at your array suggestion. I actually don't have any code yet, i'm still trying to figure out what to use at this point. My data are basically 3 different sheets with similar format, what i have done is Set worksheet selection based on what summary the user wants to see to go get the data from that one and now i'm trying to figure out the best solution, tried thinking of a loop but too slow. Application.SumIf same issue cos i have to loop it also. Arrays might be a solution, gonna read a bit more about it. Thank you

Comment: Is the 16 rows by 19 column matrix (304 cells) just an example 
or is that the total number of values to be calculated ? As I understand your question, the summation calculation takes data from 3 other sheets (same workbook ?) and uses a different formula for each of the 19 columns on the results sheet. Is that correct ?

Comment: @CDP1802 yes all in the same workbook. and it takes data for one line and column based on a condition. So sheet1 has a list for multiple months and "apples, oranges, melon" and i have to sum the values of all the fruits into 1 line, then "salad, cucumber" sum values of all lines that are categorized as vegetables on another line. and run that for month 1, month 2, month 3... etc

Comment: Does the 19 columns (n=3 to 21) represent a sum for each month over a 19 month timespan and do the 16 rows  (i = 9 To 24) represent the different categories fruit, vegetables, etc. So for example the top left cell("C9") would be the fruit total for month 1.

Comment: @CDP1802 Yes, that is exactly right. i am using right now the formula in cell as 

=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("'"&$B$5&"'!"&"E:E");INDIRECT("'"&$B$5&"'!"&"$AI:$AI");$B9)

B5 being the reference to go to use another sheet as a source. This, I think is the issue on my workbook that i was trying to solve in some better way even if a macro has to run for like 10, 20, 30 seconds i only need to update it once a day and can use the sheet freely, open, copy close in a faster way which will save me way more than the time it might run (cos it is excruciating to open this workbook)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I'm not sure this answers your question but it does paste values rather than formulas. The macro fills a 19 x 16 matrix on sheet1 using either formulae (as you have now) or values (using the same formula). Choose which method by commenting out the relevant line at the end of the loop. Put the code in an empty workbook and run the test macro, this will generate some test data on sheet 2 and the summary on sheet 1. As far as I can tell there is very little difference in the 2 methods which means something else may be causing your slow response.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

  Const MONTHS = 19

  testdata MONTHS, 1000 ' generate some data on sheet2

  Dim ws As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet
  Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
  Dim f1 As String, f2 As String, f3 As String
  Dim col As String, a1 As String, a2 As String
  Dim src As String, mth As Integer

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  ws.Cells.Clear

  src = ws.Range("B5")
  If src = "" Then src = "Sheet2"
  Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(src)

  For r = 1 To 16
    ws.Range("B" & r + 8) = "Category_" & r
    For mth = 1 To 19
      If r = 1 Then ws.Cells(8, mth + 2) = "Month " & mth

      c = mth + 4
      a1 = Chr(65 + (c - 1) Mod 26)
      a2 = ""

      ' generate column as letters (up to ZZ)
      If c > 26 Then a2 = Chr(64 + Int((c - 1) / 26))
      col = a2 & a1 & ":" & a2 & a1
      f1 = src & "!" & col
      f2 = src & "!AI:AI"
      f3 = "B" & r + 8

      ws.Cells(r + 8, mth + 2).Formula = "=SUMIFS(" & f1 & "," & f2 & "," & f3 & ")"
      'ws.Cells(r + 8, mth + 2) = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(Range(f1), Range(f2), ws.Range(f3).Value)
    Next
  Next

  MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub

Sub testdata(mth As Integer, i As Long)
  ' sheet2 data
  Dim ws, r, c
  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
  ws.Cells.Clear
  For r = 2 To i
    ws.Range("AI" & r) = "Category_" & (1 + Int(Rnd() * 16))
    For c = 5 To 4 + mth
      ws.Cells(r, c) = Int(Rnd() * 100)
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```